# Отключить автозапуск explorer.exe

Tags: windows, windows-10, автозапуск, explorer

Нужно сделать, что бы win 10 загружался без рабочего стола, пустой экран что бы был.
Попробовал в HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon в параметре Shell, затераеть explorer.exe, не помогло, оболочка всё равно загрузилось. Подскажите как быть?

Comment: Попробуйте не удалить значение, а **заменить** его на другое.

Comment: Помогло наполовину. Рабочий стол не прогрузился, нужная программа запустилась, но теперь при необходимости не получается запустить оболочку. Если захожу в диспетчер и запускаю explorer просто открывается проводник и всё

Comment: Так Вы определитесь, что необходимо: Проводник в качестве оболочки, или его отсутствие - как оболочки?